# Stop() gevent webserver is never called

Tags: python, pyside2, qthread, gevent

I am not able to stop my Gevent webserver because my `stop()` function is never called.

My Gevent webserver (`serve_forever()`) is running in a single QThread thread.
My main application is (QCoreApplication) written with PySide2.

***What i tried***

- Emitting a stop signal from the main application to the thread -> The slot in the thread, which calls `stop()`is never activated -> I presume, that server_forever() is blocking it?!
- I googled, that `stop()` shall not be called from within the same thread -> Unfortnuatelly, I wouldn't know how to safely call a method from another thread. I thought that's exactly what signal/slots are for
- I tried to use gevent.signal.signal() instead of a @QtCore.Slot(). -> This function is not accepting a custom signal, or i did it wrong

Update with working example:

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QTimer
from T_CTRL import T_CTRL

def main():

    # create application
    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None: 
        app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    
    # connect: cleanup application before quitting
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)

    # create my control object
    myCtrl = T_CTRL() 
    
    # # create helper timer, so that quit signals can be received
    timerHelper = QTimer()
    timerHelper.start(500)
    timerHelper.timeout.connect(lambda: None)  # Let the interpreter run each 500 ms.

    # run application and create main event handler
    return app.exec_()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***T_CTRL.py***

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, QCoreApplication

from T_Web_Worker import ThreadWorker
import signal
from functools import partial

class T_CTRL(QtCore.QObject): 
    
    # signals    
    sigShutdown = QtCore.Signal()   
    
    def __init__(self):  
        # init 
        super(T_CTRL, self).__init__()      

        # create objects
        self.t = QThread()
        self.worker = ThreadWorker()
    
        # connect quit signals to sigint_handler
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,  partial(self.sigint_handler, str1=""))
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, partial(self.sigint_handler, str1=""))
        
        # move worker to thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.t)        
        
        # connect: startServer() when thread has started
        self.t.started.connect(self.worker.startServer)
                
        # connect: requestServerStop() when Sigint handler has been activated
        self.sigShutdown.connect(self.worker.requestServerStop)
        
        # connect: webserver told that is has shut down, now stop the thread
        self.worker.sigServerShutdownFinished.connect(self.t.quit)
        self.worker.sigServerShutdownFinished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)

        # connect: thread has finished, now quit the application        
        self.t.finished.connect(self.t.deleteLater)
        self.t.finished.connect(self.quit_now)
       
        # start the thread
        self.t.start()

    def sigint_handler(self, signal, frame, str1):
       print ("T_CTRL: Slot 'sigint_handler' activated. Emitting signal 'sigShutdown'")
       self.sigShutdown.emit()
       QCoreApplication.processEvents()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def quit_now(self): 
       print ("_CTRL: slot 'quit_now' activated, quitting application")
       QCoreApplication.quit()
```

***T_Web_Worker***

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

class ThreadWorker(QtCore.QObject): 
    
    # init flask & tornado
    app = Flask(__name__)
    http_server = None
    
    # signal to feedback, that worker has finished
    sigServerShutdownFinished = QtCore.Signal()
    
        
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreadWorker, self).__init__() 
        
    # start requested by main thread
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def startServer(self):
        print ("T_Web_Worker: Slot 'startServer' activated")
        self.http_server = WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), self.app)       
        self.http_server.serve_forever()
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()

    # shutdown requested by main thread
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def requestServerStop(self):   
        print("T_Web_Worker: Slot 'requestServerStop' activated. Emitting signal 'sigServerShutdownFinished'")
        self.http_server.stop(timeout=5)
        self.sigServerShutdownFinished.emit()
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I added a minimal working example. I hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: Those pieces of code is not an MRE since there are many elements that are not defined

Comment: Ok, would you please tell me which pieces you mean? I read the FAQ for a MRE. From what I understand it should be code that is runnable and doesn't show to much of unnecessary code.   I can see only one variable that is not defined in the constructor ```http_server```. I thought it makes sense it this case.

Comment: There is the key: "runnable". If there are missing elements then do you think that code is runnable? missing imports, "self.app", etc.

Comment: Ok, I will double check the code one more time. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I updated the code. You were right, there were some mistakes left. I am sorry about that. Previously i merged code from two test projects and missed the errors.
The code is now runnable in my Spyder IDE (v4) and also from the terminal in a pyenv virtualenv with python 3.5.3.